# ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row for A3ENROLL

Tags: mysql

I have created the following tables:

```
A3STUDENT
CREATE TABLE A3STUNDENT(
STD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
STD_NAME VARCHAR(30),
STD_MAJOR CHAR(4),
STD_RANK CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT PK_A3STUDENT PRIMARY KEY (STD_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE A3COURSE(
CRS_TIME VARCHAR(10),
CRS_ROOM CHAR(5),
CRS_ID CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_A3COURSE PRIMARY KEY (CRS_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE A3ENROLL(
ENR_GRADE CHAR(1),
STD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
CRS_ID CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_A3ENROLL PRIMARY KEY (STD_ID, CRS_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_STD_ENR FOREIGN KEY (STD_ID) REFERENCES A3STUDENT(STD_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_CRS_ENR FOREIGN KEY (CRS_ID) REFERENCES A3COURSE(CRS_ID)
);
```

When I go to insert values such as this:

```
INSERT INTO  A3ENROLL VALUES ('A', 100, 'MGMT445');
```

I receive this error:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Hess`.`A3ENROLL`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CRS_ENR` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`CRS_ID`) REFERENCES `A3COURSE` (`CRS_ID`))

I have can't seem to understand why my data won't insert.  What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because have not data in the `A3STUNDENT` and`A3COURSE` tables.

The foreign key relationships means that a primary table that contains the central data values and a child table with identical values pointing to the parent, any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table is rejected if there is no matching candidate key value in the parent table.

The table `A3ENROLL` is taking as reference`100` and `MGMT445` that does not exist in the tables mentioned above.

Before inserting data in the `A3ENROLL` table, you must be sure that there are data in the other tables `A3STUNDENT` and `A3COURSE`, because the table`A3ENROLL` has a foreign key of `A3STUNDENT` and`A3COURSE`, this means that you must have these data in those tables, for example:

```
Select * from A3STUNDENT;

STD_ID | STD_NAME | STD_MAJOR | STD_RANK
100    | 'Zack'   | ...       | ....


Select * from A3COURSE;

CRS_ID  | CRS_ROOM | CRS_TIME
MGMT445 | ...      | ....
```

You can try to insert data in the previous tables and then insert in the table `A3ENROLL`.

Here you have more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html